# SQL Shifting 3 values down same value

Tags: sql, hive

To illustrate what I want to accomplish, as an example, table test as two columns(wk_date and value)  i want to calculate new_value. I want to take first wk_date(2/6/2021) value and copy same value for 3 weeks(2/13/2021 and 2/20/2021) and take second wk_date(2/13/2021) and copy it to next 3 wk_dates and so on...  How could i achieve this in HIVE

```
| wk_date |  value |   new_value|
    2/6/2021  100       100
    2/13/2021 200       100
    2/20/2021  300       100
    2/27/2021 400       200
    3/6/2021   500       200
    3/13/2021  600       200
    3/20/2021  700       200
    3/27/2021  800       300
    4/3/2021  900        300
    4/9/2021  1000       300
```

Comment: If you want to copy a value for 3 weeks, why is 200 copied four times?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I'm thinking of just enumerating the rows and then doing a self-join:

```
select t.*, tg.value as new_value
from (select t.*,
             ceiling(row_number() over (order by wk_date) / 3.0) as grp
      from t
     ) t join
     (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by wk_date) as grp_match
      from t
     ) tg
     on tg.grp_match = t.grp
```